# Determine the computational complexity of the following algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
s = 0
for i = 1 to n3
for j = 1 to i do
s = s + 1
```

what is mean by computational complexity?

Comment: So, the actual question is "what is computational complexity"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume each operation i in this code takes constant time c<sub>i</sub>. Then the running time can be expressed by the sum c<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub> * n3 + c<sub>3</sub> * i * n3 + c<sub>4</sub> * i * n3. We consider constant coefficients as insignificant because they only contribute a constant value regardless of the input. This gives us Θ(1) + Θ(n3) + Θ(i * n3 + 1) + Θ(i * n3). So in this case the time complexity is Θ(n3!) which is to say this algorithm runs in factorial time.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate some values (how many times s = s + 1 is executed for each iteration of i and sum up) and see what you get:

1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n * (n + 1) / 2 = n^2 / 2 + n / 2 => complexity O(n^2).